# How to Autofill cells up to a certain row based on the value in a different cell?

Tags: excel, cell, autofill, vba

So I have a cell `(let's say C3)` and I have a column in A.

Let's say that the formula I want to fill for the cells in column`A is A2 = A1 + 1` and so forth. 
I have the number `30` in `C3`.

I want excel to fill exactly 30 cells down column A using that previous formula `(A2 = A1 + 1)`. 
If I change the number in `C3` to `50`, then excel will automatically add 20 more rows in column A following the same pattern.

If I change the number in `C3 to` `10`, excel will automatically delete the rows until the first 10 rows remain.

**EDIT TO ADD**: OK so I guess I have to use macros. Anyone suggest the VBA code for this?

Comment: Unless you want to prefill the whole column with a formula (or at least as many rows as the anticipated maximum number) then you'd need VBA for this.

Comment: Darn! I guess I'll have to go learn VBA then.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of rows that you think you will have? For example, will it never be longer than 10,000 rows?

Comment: I do have a  maximum number of rows. However, for the rows I'm not using, I have to display them as empty cells rather than zero. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Actually, I think I figured out a way to do this using an if statement. Thanks guys, I'll off to see if it works.

Comment: Yeah. My solution below should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid VBA if you know a maximum possible number of rows. Use the following formula in `A2` and apply it downward until you've applied through the maximum number of columns.

```
=IF(ROW()<=$C$3,A1+1,"")
```

So in reality, you still have a formula in these cells, but you won't see any output until they are supposed to be seen. It's a work-around.